# converting from std::string to SAString

Tags: c++, sql, sqlapi++

I am using SQLAPI++ to insert values into my SQL DataBase, I am trying to extract actions from chess games and insert it as string in actions table in the database just like this (action_id=1, action_name=e4). here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    SAConnection con;
    SACommand cmd;
    try
    {
        con.Connect("test","tester","tester", SA_SQLServer_Client);
        cmd.setConnection(&con);
        std::ifstream pgnfile("sample.pgn");
        pgn::GameCollection games;
        pgnfile >> games;
        for(pgn::GameCollection::iterator itr=games.begin();itr!=games.end();itr++)
        {
            pgn::Game game = *itr;
            pgn::MoveList move_list=game.moves();
            for(pgn::MoveList::iterator itr2=move_list.begin();itr2!=move_list.end();itr2++)
            {
                pgn::Move move=*itr2;
                cmd.setCommandText("insert into actions (action_id,action_name) values (:1,:2)");
                cmd.Param(1).setAsLong() = 1;
                cmd.Param(2).setAsString() = move.black().str(); // the line that cause the error

             }
        }
    }       
}
```

the problem is in that line:

```
cmd.Param(2).setAsString() = move.black().str();
```

it can not convert from std::string to SAString! so can you tell me how to make this conversion from std::string to SAString?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your particular `SAString` class, but I believe it should be possible to construct such a string object from a C-style `const char*` string (like e.g. `SAString("Connie")`).

Given a `std::string` you can call its `c_str` method to get such a C-style string, which can probably be used to construct your `SAString`.

So, in your method call sequence:

> ```
>  ... = move.black().str();
> ```

Assuming `str` returns a `std::string`, I'd add a call to `c_str`:

```
... = move.black().str().c_str();
```

Comment: Thank u very much, your answer was very helpful !! the problem is solved :)

Comment: Yes I am new to stackOverflow :) thank u very much :)